# Azure blob batch deletion failing to delete multiple file using rest API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-blob-storage

I tried to do batch deletion at Azure blob through REST API. I have created the subrequest

```
const test = `--batch_357de4f7-6d0b-4e02-8cd2-6361411a9525\r
Content-Type: application/http\r
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r
\r
DELETE https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net/${azureDirectoryName}/${blobName} HTTP/1.1\r
Host: https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net\r
x-ms-date: ${strTime}\r
Authorization: Bearer ${authToken}\r
Content-Length: 0\r
--batch_357de4f7-6d0b-4e02-8cd2-6361411a9525--\r`
```

and my request Object for request in nodeJs is

```
{
   "url":"https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=batch",
   "method":"POST",
   "headers":{
      "Content-Type":"multipart/mixed; boundary=END_OF_PART",
      "x-ms-date":"Wed, 24 Nov 2021 12:35:05 GMT",
      "x-ms-version":"2020-04-08",
      "Content-Length":10411,
      "Authorization":"Bearer <token>"
   },
   "body":"--END_OF_PART\r\nContent-Type: application/http\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\nDELETE https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob.txt\r\nx-ms-date: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 12:35:05 GMT\r\nAuthorization: Bearer <token>\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n--END_OF_PART\r\nContent-Type: application/http\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\nDELETE https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob.txt\r\nx-ms-date: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 12:35:05 GMT\r\nAuthorization: Bearer <token>\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n--END_OF_PART\r\nContent-Type: application/http\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\nDELETE https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob.txt\r\nx-ms-date: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 12:35:05 GMT\r\nAuthorization: Bearer <token>\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n--END_OF_PART\r\nContent-Type: application/http\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\nDELETE https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob.txt\r\nx-ms-date: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 12:35:05 GMT\r\nAuthorization: Bearer <token>\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n--END_OF_PART\r\nContent-Type: application/http\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\nDELETE https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob.txt\r\nx-ms-date: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 12:35:05 GMT\r\nAuthorization: Bearer <token>\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n--END_OF_PART--"
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
'--batchresponse_144e6c6b-2bbc-4f52-900e-d213906fac30
Content-Type: application/http

HTTP/1.1 400 One of the request inputs is not valid.
x-ms-error-code: InvalidInput
x-ms-request-id: requestId
x-ms-version: 2020-04-08
Content-Length: 221
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidInput</Code><Message>One of the request inputs is not valid.
RequestId:requestId
Time:2021-11-24T12:46:45.4660320Z</Message></Error>
--batchresponse_144e6c6b-2bbc-4f52-900e-d213906fac30--'
```

Comment: Your subrequests should *not* have the host name, it should only have partial URL. Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-batch) to reframe your http request body.

Comment: this base part 'https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/ should not be present in your sub-requests.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Anand Sowmithiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14973743/anand-sowmithiran). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> Your subrequests should not have the host name, it should only have partial URL.

This base part `https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/` should not be present in your `sub-requests`

You can refer to [Blob Batch - Request Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-batch#request-body)